# Python-String to function in 'eval'

Tags: string, lisp, eval

I'm trying to build a lisp interpreter in python using 'eval'.

```
def FUNC(e1,*elements):
print(e1)

eval((input()))
```

Its working for integers.But is there any way I can use this to input strings?

eg: when I input:

```
F(a,b,3,5,2)
```

The above code should print:

```
a
```

I don't want to input it as: F('a','b',3,5,2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to convey a string value is by enclosing it within quote. Other way to do it is by declaring a string variable separately and send it as a parameter instead. However, when you print a string query in interactive command window, it won't be printed with quotes aroun